# BigQuery - reducing to unique records within a field

Tags: google-bigquery, unique, distinct

I have a table with fields like this:

```
ID    Field 1           Field 2
1     22,34,05,44,44    01,02,02,03
2     11,01,05          02,02,01,01,22
```

How could I transform it in BigQuery (strandardSQL) to show unique records only and sorted from big to small?

So that the output will look like this:

```
ID    Field 1           Field 2
1     05,22,34,44       01,02,03
2     01,05,11          01,02,22
```

I tried with `Split` but then I'm running in hundreds of duplicates, also `window` functions don't allow `distinct` to combine the things together later.

Please help to figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the strings to turn them into arrays, then deduplicate using `DISTINCT` and sort using `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT
  ID,
  ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT x FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(field1, ',')) AS x ORDER BY x) AS field1,
  ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT x FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(field2, ',')) AS x ORDER BY x) AS field2
FROM `project-name`.dataset.table
```

If you want to turn the arrays into comma-separated strings again, you can use the `ARRAY_TO_STRING` function:

```
SELECT
  ID,
  ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT x FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(field1, ',')) AS x ORDER BY x), ',') AS field1,
  ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT x FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(field2, ',')) AS x ORDER BY x), ',') AS field2
FROM `project-name`.dataset.table
```